# jsf ajax button to remove element from list, but ajax do not rerender datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable

I have strange problem. I got a dataTable in which I present list of objects. Here's the code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{XXXX.questions}" var="q" binding="#{varQ}" id="YYY">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      header
    </f:facet>
     #{q.question}
  </h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="-" action="#{XXX.removeQuestion(varSurvey.index, varSec.index, varQ.rowIndex)}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="YYY"/>
   </h:commandButton>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

As you can see - I got a button to remove one item from list. Method works fine, it removes element I want to be removed, but the datatable is not refreshed. I have no idea why.

My bean is SessionScoped, I got almost identical table in other part of my page, and it works which completely confuses me.

My bean method is like this :

```
public void removeQuestion(Integer surveyIndex, Integer sectionIndex, int questionIndex){
    surveyList.get(surveyIndex).getSections().get(sectionIndex).getQuestions().remove(questionIndex);
}
```

so as you can see - it's almost basic example.

Here is code for my other table from same page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{XXX.answers}" id="ZZZ" var="ans">
  <h:column>
     <h:inputText value="#{ans.choice}" styleClass="form-control">
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"/>
     </h:inputText>
  </h:column>
<f:facet name="footer">
  <h:commandButton value="+" action="#{XXX.addMoreQuestions()}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="ZZZ"/>
  </h:commandButton>
</f:facet>
</h:dataTable>
```

and method:

```
public void addMoreQuestions(){
    answers.add(new Choice("question"));
}
```

And this works - when I click button, it adds one more question to list, and rerenders datatable with one more option.

Comment: Have you removed the item from the list `XXXX.questions`?

Comment: as I wrote before - yes, method for removal works fine - when I click button, and then manualy refresh page datatable is one record shorter.